# What are the size requirements for App Icons and Tile Images in WMAppManifest.xml?

Tags: windows-phone-8

What is the size requirements for App Icons and Tile Images in WMAppManifest.xml?

Is it 62x62 for icons? I can't seem to find it documented anywhere, and Visual Studio seems to accept any image size I put in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
The application icon (ApplicationIcon.png): For all res, 99x99 px.
Small iconic tile (IconicTileSmall.png: For all resolutions 110x110 px.
Medium iconic tile (IconicTileMedium.png): For all res, 202x202 px.
Small flip or cycle tile (FlipcycleTileSmall.png): For all resolutions 159x159 px.
Medium flip or cycle tile (FlipCycleTileMedium): For all resolutions 336x336 px.
Large flip or cycle tile (FlipCycleTileWide.png): For all res 691x336.
```

Comment: is this the same for Windows Phone 7.1 and Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight projects and for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: do you have any reference URLs for this info?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis If you googled it, you could have found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/designmichel/archive/2013/02/15/the-windows-phone-8-design-style.aspx